# Sed and two consecutive lines

Tags: sed

I have a log file of an application and I must filter only the users who didn't logon successfully (which is registered as ok right after user id)

The logfile has entries as follows.

```
user2
user5
user7
user1
user1
user1 ok
user8
user9
user3
user3 ok
```

Expected output should be as follows.

```
user2
user5
user7
user8
user9
```

I'm trying:

```
sed "/user/N;/ok/d"
```

No result. I keep getting "user 1"

```
user2
user5
user7
user1
user8
user9
```

Comment: Both `user1` and `user3` failed to log in, right? Would you want to see `user1` if he/she failed after a successful attempt?

Answer (score 3):

This works, unless i have understand your question in a wrong way:

```
$ grep -v -f <(grep " ok$" aa.txt |cut -d' ' -f1) aa.txt
user2
user5
user7
user8
user9
```

In reality we grep the file for all the names marked as ok, and then we use these names as a pattern to be excluded from the same file in order to get "not ok" logins.

This is based on fact that since user1 had at the end a successful login (even after three tries), user1 is not considered as a failure, thus all user1 attempts are excluded.
grep -v : exclude pattern
grep -f : load patterns from file , here a process substitution that holds the successful logins.

PS1: file aa.txt is one of my local files that i have pasted your data inside.

Update:
Using `<(grep " ok$" aa.txt |cut ...)` with a space before ok, will ensure that usernames who failed to login but include "ok" in their names will not be matched (i.e user Bangok)

Comment: @skldfh updated

Comment: @skldfh Answer updated again (thanks don_crissti!). Now should be almost perfect.